# How can I speed up the process of integrating a complex function?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, probability-density, n-quads

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.now()
plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
XX=[None, 11.3, 14.8, 7.6, 10.5, 12.7, 3.9, 11.2, 5.4, 8.5, 5.0, 4.4, 7.3, 2.9, 5.7, 6.2, 7.3, 3.3, 4.2, 5.5, 4.2]
I = [None,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
N=20
    # Задаем G-ю функцию которая включает в себя произведения плотностей вероятности
    # каждого независимого результата Xi в которых МО и СКО изменяются по линейной зависимости
def G(M1, Mn, S1, Sn):
    def loc (M1, Mn, i, n):
        return (M1*(n-i)/(n-1)) + (Mn*(i-1)/(n-1)) 
    def scale (S1, Sn, i, n):
        return (S1*(n-i)/(n-1)) + (Sn*(i-1)/(n-1))
    def fnorm (x):
        return (np.exp((-x**2)/2))/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))
    def y (M1, Mn, S1, Sn, i, n, x):
        return (x-loc(M1,Mn,i,n))/scale(S1,Sn,i,n)
    def F (M1, Mn, S1, Sn, i, n, x):
        return (fnorm(y(M1, Mn, S1, Sn, i, n, x)))/scale(S1, Sn, i, n)
    # Распаковка значений x и i из глобальных переменных
    x = XX[1:]
    i = I[1:]
    n=N
    # Вычисляем значение функции F для каждого x и i
    values=[F(M1, Mn, S1, Sn, i_val, n, x_val) for i_val, x_val in zip(i, x)]
    
    # Вычисляем произведение всех значений
    result = np.prod(values)
    
    return result
    # находим сомножитель К для получения общей ПВ оценок
options={'epsrel':1e-20, 'epsabs':1e-20}
K, errorK = integrate.nquad(G, ranges=[[0, 30],[0, 10],[0, 10],[0, 10]], opts=[options, options, options, options])
# K = 2.9613332457351404e-18    errorK = 9.999171231431291e-21
    #  формируем ПВ оценок
def pdf(Mn, S1, Sn,       M1):
    return (G(M1, Mn, S1, Sn) / K)
    #  строим график автономной ПВ оценок для параметра М1 (уменьшаем значения ошибок для оперативности)
def pdf_m1 (M1):
    return [(integrate.tplquad(pdf, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, args=(m,), epsabs=0.1, epsrel=0.1)[0]) for m in M1]
x = np.arange(4, 16, 0.2)
plt.plot(x, pdf_m1(x), 'k', lw=3)
plt.ylim(bottom=0)
plt.title('Fm1(m1)')
plt.show()
    # находим несмещенную оценку М1 и её ско sm1 (примерные значения по методу ММП М1 = 9.66)
def F1 (M1):
    return integrate.tplquad(pdf, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, args=(M1,))[0]
M1, _ = integrate.quad(lambda M1: M1 * F1(M1), 4, 16)
print(M1)
Dm1, _ = integrate.quad (lambda x: ((x-M1)**2) * F1(x), 4, 16)
sm1 = np.sqrt(Dm1)
print(sm1)
print("Время вычисления М1 и СКОм1:", datetime.datetime.now()-start)
```

The problem is efficiency. The code is running for so long, taking up to 15 hours! The task is mostly based on integrating functions. The example only considers integration for one variable, but in reality, you need to integrate for every variable specified in the PDF.

I use the Spyder IDE for this project.

I need to integrate functions with 4 variables or more.

Comment: Just few tips: 1. remove the plotting stuff, 2. create smaller example (that runs in shorter time), 3. use [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to determine where your code spends the most time, 4. make the comments in english. If you identify the bottlenecks I suggest to [edit] your question with the findings.

Comment: Alexey, depending on the number of dimensions, you might need to consider different algorithms. In a small number of dimensions, repeated 1-d methods and their generalizations are effective, but the number of function evaluations increases exponentially. In a large number of dimensions, Monte Carlo methods are the only workable approach from what I know. In between, maybe around 4 to 6, I forget, there is a spot where quasi-MC (also called low discrepancy sequences) is more efficient than MC. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: I edited according to your comments and used qmc. Values of K = 0

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: avoid impossible tolerances and consider QMC integration.

---

One thing that would help is to avoid specifying tolerances that cannot possibly be achieved. Double precision floats have an epsilon on the order of `1e-16`, so you cannot possibly hope to achieve `1e-20` relative error, but it has a huge impact on your runtime.

Consider, for instance:

```py
from time import perf_counter
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from scipy.integrate import nquad
rng = np.random.default_rng(23925340854238936)
options={'epsrel':1e-20, 'epsabs':1e-20}

for d in range(1, 4):
    cov = rng.random((d, d))
    cov = cov @ cov.T
    dist = multivariate_normal(cov=cov)
    x = np.asarray([(0, 1)]*d)
    tic = perf_counter()
    res = nquad(lambda *x: dist.pdf(x), x)
    # res = nquad(lambda *x: dist.pdf(x), x, opts=[options]*d)
    toc = perf_counter()
    print(toc - tic)
    ref = dist.cdf(x[:, 1], lower_limit=x[:, 0])

# 0.0012877020001269557
# 0.08465272499984167
# 0.5809959000000617
```

The execution time of numerical integration scales very poorly with dimensionality, and the curse is exacerbated by the tight tolerances. When we use your tolerances, the runtimes look like:

```py
# 0.004921189000015147
# 0.4714967869999782
# 241.41230427999994
```

And all that time gave very little in terms of improved accuracy. With no `option`, the error of the 3d integral is `res[0] - ref = 4.969670549248573e-07`, and when we use the tolerances, the error is `-3.4931814399397076e-07`.

In fact, for your quadruple integral, we can already see:
`# K = 2.9613332457351404e-18    errorK = 9.999171231431291e-21`
The second number is an absolute error estimate. I'm not sure what the *true* error is, but this means that the estimated relative error is around `3e-3`. If you're not achieving great accuracy anyway, you might as well use [`scipy.integrate.qmc_quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.qmc_quad.html), which can get reasonable accuracy in much less time.

```py
from time import perf_counter
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import nquad, qmc_quad
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
rng = np.random.default_rng(23925340854238936)

d = 4
cov = rng.random((d, d))
cov = cov @ cov.T
dist = multivariate_normal(cov=cov)
x = np.asarray([(0, 1)]*d)

ref = dist.cdf(x[:, 1], lower_limit=x[:, 0])

tic = perf_counter()
res = nquad(lambda *x: dist.pdf(x), x)
toc = perf_counter()
print(f"nquad    | Time: {toc - tic}, Error: {abs((res[0] - ref)/ref)})")

tic = perf_counter()
res = qmc_quad(lambda x: dist.pdf(x.T), *x.T)
toc = perf_counter()
print(f"qmc_quad | Time: {toc - tic}, Error: {abs((res[0] - ref)/ref)})")
# nquad    | Time: 13.483493682000244, Error: 2.8983787517192293e-05)
# qmc_quad | Time: 0.0281571279997479, Error: 0.000120747399615769)
```

If you need better accuracy from `qmc_quad` in the same amount of time (at the expense of *error estimate* accuracy), decrease `n_estimates` and increase `n_points` by the same factor. If you can spare time for increased accuracy - since this is already a massive speedup - just increase `n_points`.

Comment: Thanks!!! I edited according to your comments and used qmc. But I have values of K = 0 ((( Look please.

Comment: That's a different question. This question is about speeding up high dimensional integral calculations, and it sounds like you have your answer. I would suggest writing a new question in which you give a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of using qmc_quad and getting an integral of zero where that is unexpected. To show that the problem is specific to `qmc_quad`, show that `nquad` gives a finite nonzero result for the same problem. Include all code required to run the example and no more.

Comment: I'd also recommend reverting your recent changes to the question. You completely changed the code, so it is no longer consistent with the title or the answer. S.O. is about creating a repository of questions and answers that are useful to others, not just solving your problem.